# eliminates every occurrence of x from a list of integers in lisp

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

I need to write a lisp function that eliminates every occurrence of x from a list of integers. For example, (elim 7 '(7 6 8 8 7 7 9 0))  returns (6 8 8 9 0)

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  And why do you need to write this?  Common Lisp (with which the question is tagged) already includes a `remove` function.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to write it;  it's already written for you, and it's called [`remove`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm):

```
CL-USER> (remove 7 '(7 6 8 8 7 7 9 0))
;=> (6 8 8 9 0)
```

If you really need it to be called `elim`, you can use `(setf fdefinition)`:

```
CL-USER> (setf (fdefinition 'elim) (fdefinition 'remove))
;=> ...
CL-USER> (elim 7 '(7 6 8 8 7 7 9 0))
;=> (6 8 8 9 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really need to write it, the usual ways apply:

**recursive**

```
(defun elim (value list)
  (if list
    (let ((c (car list)))
      (if (= c value)
        (elim value (cdr list))
        (cons c (elim value (cdr list)))))
    (reverse list)))
```

**tail recursive**

```
(defun elim (value list)
  (labels ((sub (list res)
             (if list
               (let ((c (car list)))
                 (if (= c value)
                   (sub (cdr list) res)
                   (sub (cdr list) (cons c res))))
               (reverse res))))
    (sub list '())))
```

**loop**

```
(defun elim (value list)
  (loop for i in list
    unless (= i value)
    collect i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recurse down the list until the list is empty.  If the head of the list equals the provided item don't include it in the output:

```
(defun elim (value list)
  (if (null list)
      '()
      (let ((next (car list))
            (rest (cdr list)))
        (if (= value next)
            (elim value rest)
            (cons next (elim value rest))))))
```